# Append HTML to a tag using PHP HTML Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing

I am working on a project in which I will need to use PHP to modify the contents of any given website. To do this I am using this [PHP HTML Parser](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser).

Now, I need to be able to add a `<style>` tag to the end of the `<head>` of a document that's been loaded to `$html` using `$html->loadFromFile($url)` but I cannot seem to find an `append()` method in any of the classes. Is there any way for me to achieve this?

Here is my code

```
require("vendor/autoload.php");
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
$html = new Dom;

$url = "https://www.example.com";
$html->loadFromFile($url);

// I need to do this:
$css = "<style>#custom{css:code;}.goes{over:here;}</style>"
$html->find("head")->append($css);
```

Comment: The modification limitations of this library seem to be to alter existing elements and to remove elements (https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser#modifying-the-dom), may be worth looking into DOMDocument and loadHTML (http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it

```
$head = $html->getElementsByTagName('head');
$head->appendChild($css);
```

Comment: Isn't it `getElementsByTagName()` return an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the instruction for appending an element in the [documentation](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) under "How to access the HTML element's attributes?"->"Tips".
In this case it would be:

```
$head = $html->find("head")[0];
$head->outertext = $head->outertext . $css;
```

Comment: That's not the parser that the topic starter talks about